# How to implement dynamic measurements like sp and % in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Previously, there were units like `%` and `sp` and many more. But it seems there is only `dp` in **Compose**.

Comment: @Johann Can you please me this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sp is used for text. This is still available:

```kotlin
Text("Cats are cool", textSize = 14.sp)
```

For %, you use `weight`. This example sets the width of the first column to 90% and the second to 10%:

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth) {
   Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.9f)) {

   }

   Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f)) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Can `Modifier.weight()` be used for a composable whose parent is neither **Row** nor **Column**

Comment: It can be used for many things but not all things. It has a scope like all modifiers. You should just try it out on something and see if it works.

Comment: I noticed that the official docs have been updated and include a list of modifiers now: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers-list. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you found it useful. Thanks!