# Content padding parameter it is not used

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I recently started working with Jetpack Compose. I've got the following composable:

```
@Composable
fun SearchScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { SearchBar() },
        content = {
            Column (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                // some nested Composables
            }
        }
    )
}
```

But with this code as-is, the whole code within `content = {...}` is being underlined in red saying `Jetpack Compose: Content padding parameter it is not used`. I already read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209466/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-paddingvalues-parameter-in-a-scaffold) Stackoverflow Post that actually, `PaddingValues` only are provided in a Scaffold if the `bottomBar` is set, which obviously is not the case here. So I do not understand why I am getting this error.

Note: The app actually does use a `BottomNavigation`, but not within the `Composable` that I showed above. Can it be that this is still somehow propagated here?

Comment: I copy-pasted your composable and I can't reproduce the underlined error. I have also put the `content` argument as a trailing lambda and the code works fine.

Comment: Interesting. Could it be related to my compose version? I am using `compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha08`, as I need the FilterChip Composable. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I am on `composeVersion = "1.1.1"` and I have seen `@Pylyp Dukhov` answer below which clarifies the differences.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

It's required to use padding parameter, passed into `Scaffold` `content` composable. You should apply it to the topmost container/view in `content`:

```
content = { padding ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(padding)
    // ...
```

This is done to prevent layout problems, for example, when the scaffold has a bottom bar, without the use of this padding part of your view will be under the bar.

You can always suppress it with `@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")`, but I would recommend doing this only when you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it! One follow up question though, if I have a `NavHost` set as a child of a `Scaffold`, would I just set the padding directly to the `NavHost`, or do I need to somehow pass this padding to the seperate composables that are going to be displayed within the `NavHost`?

Comment: @BenjyTec you should apply it to the topmost container, in this case `NavHost`

Comment: I've applied this to my top most container and still get the error, supressing it seems to be the only way of getting rid of it

Comment: @alfietap show the code how you did it, e.g. using [gist](https://gist.github.com). it should work for sure, if your code is correct and it doesn't work - it should be reported as IDE bug

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alfietapping/f064e20e82b4d84aaf2c304be165cbdf - AppNavigation contains the NavHost

Comment: @alfietap it doesn't show an error to me. Make sure you're using latest IDE and android gradle plugin. Try creating a new project with the same code to see if you can reproduce it. If yes, [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) including this sample project, your IDE version and sample project.

Comment: Yeesh. I was like WTF; I copied a Composable from another project I'm working on where it was fine, and didn't see why it had a problem in my new project. My older project must have a bit older version of Compose I guess. Jeez thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I seen a bug in version alpha and I was using SmallTopAppBar()
Scaffold didn't provide paddings to two composables was on top of each other.
After updating it, just realized the bug fixed and Scaffold has itself a padding so composables is not on top of rach other anymore.

Usage:

```
  Scaffold(topBar = { AppBar() }) { paddingValues ->
  AnyComposable(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){

  }
```

Answer (score 10):

Add the `it` keyword:

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = { SearchBar() },
        content = { it
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()))
```

This should work.

Comment: Wild, it works. but why can you elaborate more?

Comment: @JugertMucoimaj Your question is answered by Phil Dukhov below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72085218/4891188

Comment: From my understanding, this removes the the linting error, as the padding parameter is "used" within the content Composable with the `it` keyword. However, this does not apply the padding, and thus is rather a workaround than a fix. Refer to the accepted answer for a valid way to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this annotation :

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
```

Answer (score 2):

use padding in **Column** and delete **content**

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = { SearchBar() }
){
    Column(Modifier.padding(it)) {
                ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by passing the content's padding to the Modifier padding method:

#### Example:

```kotlin
 content = { padding ->
                MainScreenContainer(
                    navController = navController,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)
                )
            }
```

Answer (score -5):

app build.gradle add this:

```
 buildFeatures {
    compose = true
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=androidx.compose.animation.graphics.ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=com.google.accompanist.navigation.material.ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi"
}
```