# Content padding parameter it is not used error in kotlin jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I solve this issue `Content padding parameter it is not used` in kotlin ? I made a dictionary app and I edited some codes and I have a problem like this Where should I add the content padding? how can i fix it?

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {


    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {

        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    backgroundColor = bar,
                    title = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Main Menu",
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontSize = 22.sp
                        )
                    },
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SearchScreen.route) }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_look_for_96),
                                contentDescription = "search",
                                tint = Color.Unspecified,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        ) {
            gridView(navController)   // problem is hear
            
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to specify the name?
> { padding ->

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084865/content-padding-parameter-it-is-not-used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is not actually an error that will prevent your application from running, and it is even possible to ignore it, **however** if you ignore and do not use the `padding` provided by the `Scaffold` it may happen that components inside the `Scaffold` are overlapped by `Scaffold` components, for example the `top bar`.

To avoid this problem in the right way you will need something like this:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        // ...
    }
) { innerPadding -> // padding calculated by scaffold
    // it doesn't have to be a column,
    // can be another component that accepts a modifier with padding
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues = innerPadding) // padding applied here
    ) {
        // all content should be here
    }
}
```